# How to get the keys of a Dictionary<string, object> into a sorted string[]

Tags: generics, sorting, dictionary, c#-4.0

What's the best way (*) to get the keys of a `Dictionary<string, object>` into a `string[]` (sorted alphabetically)?

Example:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
d.Add("b", 1);
d.Add("f", 2);
d.Add("a", 3);

string[] sortedKeys = ...;
// sortedKeys should contain ["a", "b", "f"]
```

(*) what I mean with "best way" is probably: *it should be easy to write and read, but should still result in good performance*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "best" - but I'd use:

```
string[] sortedKeys = d.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Slightly more efficient but less fluent:

```
string[] sortedKeys = d.Keys.ToArray();
Array.Sort(sortedKeys);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was struggling with the `OrderBy()` method

Comment: There's also the more LINQy syntax: `(from k in d.Keys orderby k select k).ToArray()` if you have trouble with `OrderBy()`.

Comment: @Gabe: True - although I would advise people to learn both forms... here the query expression is only adding noise compared with the extension method form, IMO.